# I can't figure out why I can't remove duplicates from a Pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, drop-duplicates

I am trying to update a Pandas Dataframe with data from an API and have it written to .csv, I need to be sure it does not contain duplicate rows.

I have been checking on here to see what the problem might be (for example forgetting to add inplace=True), but this doesn't seem to be the case.

So... I have pandas read the csv

```
df = pd.read_csv(file)
```

Then I download some more data from the API (I ensured I had duplicate lines) and create df2 (the csv was written by the same code so I am sure that a duplicate line is exactly the same).
Now I need to append a dataframe to the other and then drop the duplicates:

```
df = df.append(df2, ignore_index=True)
df.drop_duplicates(subset=None, keep='first', inplace=True)
```

then I tried

```
df = df.drop_duplicates()
```

I would expect not to see any duplicate row with both, but I must be missing something as those are still there and I can't figure out why.
I did check if someone else's question was addressing this, but I noticed how the problem is normally missing the inplace=True part... which I didn't.

Comment: You already tried `df = df.drop_duplicates()`? Or,  `df = df.drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)`  What happens if you omit all the arguments except inplace?

Comment: I tried it now, but to no avail... editing my question. Thanks.

Comment: Ah, okay.  I see you got an answer.  I've never used the keep argument, but now I'm thinking I should! lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you need ?

```
df.drop_duplicates(keep=False)
```

Comment: Indeed it was... I didn't understand that keep='first' meant to keep the first duplicate (I thought it meant to keep the first instance). Thanks a lot.